# CSS Float with more than one element

Tags: html, css, image, text

I have a picture with `float: left`. The goal is to have 2 more text box beside the picture. But the second textbox goes under the first text box doesn't matter if i set a width or not. What is going wrong there?

I thought it is possible to float just one element to float all the coming ones until you clear the element which should not be floated anymore

```css
.CollaboDescription {
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding: 2.5%;
  border: 2px solid #000
}

.CollaboProfilePicture {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px
}

.CollaboPersonalDescription_1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 400px 0 0;
  font: 15px Oxygen, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-decoration: none
}

.CollaboPersonalDescriptionNoFloat {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  font: 15px Oxygen, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div class="ce_image CollaboProfilePicture first block">
  <figure class="image_container" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" itemprop="associatedMedia">
    <img src="https://www.martin-missfeldt.de/images-pictures/grafik-illustration/bild-mit-wort-bild.jpg" alt="" itemprop="image" width="250" height="333">
  </figure>
</div>
<div class="ce_text CollaboPersonalDescription_1 block">
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: x 100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="width: 15.0528%; height: 28px; padding-right: 60px;">Geburtsjahr:</td>
        <td style="width: 84.9472%; height: 28px;">2000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="width: 15.0528%; height: 28px;">Lieblingsplatz:</td>
        <td style="width: 84.9472%; height: 28px;">Jumppark Zürich</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="width: 15.0528%; height: 28px;">Favorite trick:</td>
        <td style="width: 84.9472%; height: 28px;">Tuck No Hander</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="width: 15.0528%; height: 28px;">Bike Model:</td>
        <td style="width: 84.9472%; height: 28px;">Canyon Stiched 360</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="width: 15.0528%; height: 28px;">Hoodie:</td>
        <td style="width: 84.9472%; height: 28px;">GBSS Black</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px;">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<!-- indexer::stop -->
<div class="mod_eventlist CollaboPersonalDescriptionNoFloat block">
  <h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
  <div class="event layout_upcoming upcoming even first last cal_4" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <time datetime="2018-10-24" class="date" itemprop="startDate">24.10.2018</time>
    <a href="https://www.zueritrails.ch/jumppark/" title="DirtContest Jumppark (Mittwoch, 24.10.2018)" itemprop="url">DirtContest Jumppark</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- indexer::continue -->
<div class="ce_hyperlink last block">
  <figure class="image_container" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/robin.bachofner.509" class="hyperlink_img" rel="" itemprop="contentUrl">
      <img src="assets/images/a/Instagram%20button_black-e3e5b7ad.png" alt="" itemprop="image" width="80" height="80">
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the following properties to those "text blocks":

```
display: inline-block;
width: 300px;
vertical-align: top;
```

(and look at the snippet in full page mode)

I.e., `inline-block;` allows serveral blocks next to each other, a fixed width makes sure they don't stretch across the whole container (which would be the default if there is enough content inside them), and `vertical-align: top` just makes sure that if more than one of them are next to each other, they are aligned along their top (instead of the default `baseline`)

```css
.CollaboDescription {
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding: 2.5%;
  border: 2px solid #000
}

.CollaboProfilePicture {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px
}

.CollaboPersonalDescription_1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font: 15px Oxygen, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-decoration: none
}

.CollaboPersonalDescriptionNoFloat {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  font: 15px Oxygen, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div class="ce_image CollaboProfilePicture first block">
  <figure class="image_container" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" itemprop="associatedMedia">
    <img src="https://www.martin-missfeldt.de/images-pictures/grafik-illustration/bild-mit-wort-bild.jpg" alt="" itemprop="image" width="250" height="333">
  </figure>
</div>
<div class="ce_text CollaboPersonalDescription_1 block">
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: x 100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="width: 15.0528%; height: 28px; padding-right: 60px;">Geburtsjahr:</td>
        <td style="width: 84.9472%; height: 28px;">2000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="width: 15.0528%; height: 28px;">Lieblingsplatz:</td>
        <td style="width: 84.9472%; height: 28px;">Jumppark Zürich</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="width: 15.0528%; height: 28px;">Favorite trick:</td>
        <td style="width: 84.9472%; height: 28px;">Tuck No Hander</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="width: 15.0528%; height: 28px;">Bike Model:</td>
        <td style="width: 84.9472%; height: 28px;">Canyon Stiched 360</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 16px;">
        <td style="width: 15.0528%; height: 28px;">Hoodie:</td>
        <td style="width: 84.9472%; height: 28px;">GBSS Black</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px;">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<!-- indexer::stop -->
<div class="mod_eventlist CollaboPersonalDescriptionNoFloat block">
  <h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
  <div class="event layout_upcoming upcoming even first last cal_4" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <time datetime="2018-10-24" class="date" itemprop="startDate">24.10.2018</time>
    <a href="https://www.zueritrails.ch/jumppark/" title="DirtContest Jumppark (Mittwoch, 24.10.2018)" itemprop="url">DirtContest Jumppark</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- indexer::continue -->
<div class="ce_hyperlink last block">
  <figure class="image_container" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/robin.bachofner.509" class="hyperlink_img" rel="" itemprop="contentUrl">
      <img src="assets/images/a/Instagram%20button_black-e3e5b7ad.png" alt="" itemprop="image" width="80" height="80">
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working now!